# use of min and count from 2 different table in ibm db2

Tags: sql, count, db2, min

How can i show which tutor teach the least subject?

[image: Tables]

this is my syntax but I'm getting

> Error code 42607

```
select 
  tut_id, 
  min(count(session_code)) as subject_taught 
from 
  tutor,
  class  
where 
  tutor.tutor id = class.tut_id 
group by tut_id
```

Expected output:

```
tut_id  subject_taught 
  id2          1
```

Comment: you can't use aggregate of an aggregate in the same query.

Comment: How do you want to handle the case when there are tutors having the same amount of subject taught that are minimum?

Comment: @vkp this is the error msg i get when i execute

Comment: @Consider Me it should display both if there exist 2 same lowest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple:

```
WITH Subjects_Taught AS (SELECT tutor_id, COUNT(*) AS subjects_taught
                         FROM Class
                         GROUP BY tutor_id)

SELECT tutor_id, subjects_taught
FROM Subjects_Taught
WHERE subjects_taught = (SELECT MIN(subjects_taught)
                         FROM Subjects_Taught)
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c7231/2/0)</kbd>

---

So what's going on in the statement?

First, the Common Table Expression ->

```
WITH Subjects_Taught AS (SELECT tutor_id, COUNT(*) AS subjects_taught
                         FROM Class
                         GROUP BY tutor_id)
```

This defines an in-query view or temporary table.  These are handy for abstracting certain details away, or when you end up referring to the same info twice in a statement (as we do here).  Essentially, you end up with a table that looks like this:

> id1   |   2
>    id2   |   1
>    id3   |   2

... so then the only thing left is to restrict ourselves to rows of **this** table that meet the minimum:

```
WHERE subjects_taught = (SELECT MIN(subjects_taught)
                         FROM Subjects_Taught)
```

... we reference our virtual table a second time, getting the minimum, as if it were a normal table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a DB2 available now but as far as I can see [here](http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-112_sqlstate_42607.html) you cannot nest aggregate functions in DB2:

```
$... min(count(session_code))...
```

Comment: yes, what u have said is the error msg i get from executing the sql command